# Magento: кнопка "Следить за ценой товара"

Tags: magento

Мне нужна кнопка "Следить за ценой" в карточке товара.

Я так понимаю, это обычные уведомления пользователю в случае, если цена на товар изменилась.

Говорят, есть стандартная функция для кнопки "Следить за ценой" (Follow Price), не могу найти ничего. Скажите, кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено, стандартный модуль productalert выводится в карточке товара простым `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>`.

У меня просто была измененная карточка товара, также нужно не забыть включить отображение ссылки в админке путь: конфигурация/каталог/каталог/оповещение о товаре (это перевод моей локализации).